# Non-Resolvable dependency issue while using jboss.fuse.bom

Tags: maven, jbossfuse

I came across the following maven build issue while trying to use jboss.fuse.bom as dependency.

```
    Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.fuse.bom:jboss-fuse-parent:pom:6.1.0.redhat-399 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
The dependacy
```

Dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.redhat-399</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that, this dependency is not available in central repository. So, I defined jboss repository in the pom to resolve this issue, as shown below:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo2</id>
        <name>jboss repo</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/ea/</url>
    </repository>       
</repositories>
```

Now the build will use default repository(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and the newly defined jboss repository to resolve the dependencies. 
Reference: [Setting up multiple maven repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)